# I am reading file but while reading,it is reading last character one time extra?

Tags: c++

I am trying to read file by following code

```
void main()
{ 
   int i=0;
   ifstream fout1 ("Aj.txt",ios::binary);
   if (fout1.is_open())
   {
      while(fout1)
      {
         i++;
         fout1.get(ch1);
         cout<<ch1;
      }
      cout<<i;
      fout1.close();
    }
    else
    { 
       cout << "Unable to open file";
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

here this code reads whole file but it goes into loop one extra time i.e if there are 4character in file then in loop it will iterate 5 time .how to correct it or overcome it.

Comment: while (fout1.get(ch1)) { cout << ch1; ++i }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code reads until the `eof` flag is set, but the `eof` flag is not set until a read actually fails. Which means when `fout1.get(ch1)` reads the last character, `eof` is *not* set yet.  So it displays, and checks `fout` which is still good, so it re-enters the loop.  Then `fout1.get(ch1)` fails because of eof, and it displays the previous value of `ch1` again.  The correct way to write that loop is:

```
while(fout1.get(ch1)) {  //false when it can't read any more characters
    i++;
    cout<<ch1;
}
cout<<i;
fout1.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

After reading the 4th character the stream is still in a good state, so it tries to read a 5th character and at that time it encounters the end of file. You should check the stream state after calling `get`. For instance:

```
while( fout1.get(ch1) )
{
    cout << ch1;
    ++i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy mistake to make if you're not familiar with iostreams.  `stream.eof()` will be *false* if you have merely *read the last character in the file*.  It only becomes true when you *try to read **past** the end of the file*.  You need an inner loop that looks like this:

```
for (;;)
{
    fout1.get(ch1);
    if (!fout1) break;
    cout << ch1;
    i++;
}
```